# Boost -gd lib file

Tags: c++, boost

After building the boost library (so I could use the filesystem namespace) I found in the `stage/lib` folder the following files with filesystem in the name:

```
libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_51 (838 kb)

libboost_filesystem-vc100-gd-mt-1_51 (4210 kb)
```

Notice the -gd in the second one. I also put in the size in parenthesis. So, what's the difference? Which one do I use?

Comment: Have no idea, but my guess is debug information.

Comment: Possibly dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715164/how-can-i-decode-the-boost-library-naming

Comment: @ForEveR  Oops, I didn't find anything when I searched stack overflow, google, and the boost doc. I must have missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`-gd` is for debug version of libs. Use `-gd-mt` for building in debug configuration and `-mt` for release configurations.