# Link error with libCGAL-vc120-mt-sgd-4.5.1.lib and cant seem to find or build it

Tags: c++, cmake, cgal

Hey I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to CGAL and CMake but I've gotten to the point where everything seems to be running except for this link error:

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libCGAL-vc120-mt-sgd-4.5.1.lib'

trouble is I cant seem to find a reference to this lib anywhere am I building wrong?

I can see a 'libCGAL-vc120-mt-gd-4.5.1.lib' in my cgal lib dir which links fine. I'm not sure what the difference between gd and sgd is though and how to make it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What OS is this? Linux?

Comment: ***I'm not sure what the difference between gd and sgd is though and how to make it.*** I believe the difference is sgd = static debug where gd = debug dll. Looks like it follows the boost naming. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715164/how-can-i-decode-the-boost-library-naming

Comment: This is visual studio 2013 by the error message and library naming. vc120 == Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Windows 8.1 - Visual Studio 2013. Thought it might have to do with static linking I've tried forcing it to make with the static boost libraries but still doesn't generate an -sgd- version, only an -gd-, when i compile in vs. Is there some sort of flag that I'm not aware of that i need to add in either vs or c-make?

Comment: With CMake a lot of libraries use a BUILD_SHARED option (check in cmake-gui) to build shared libraries (dlls). I do not use cgal so I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The naming `libCGAL-vc120-mt-sgd-4.5.1.lib` shows that you are compiling a program, that uses CGAL, using the linker flag `/MTd` (Debug, and link the C++ runtime *statically*).

The CMake scripts of CGAL do not support linking with the static runtime. They only support `/MD` or `/MDd`. I suggest you change that linker flag in your setup.

Alternately, you can try to change the CMake scripts of CGAL, but I do not recommend that solution.