# What's the meaning of "mt" in QuantLib-vc110-mt.lib?

Tags: c++, compilation, quantlib

I compiled Quantlib library in vs2012 under "release" and got the lib file, QuantLib-vc110-mt.lib.

My question is what's the meaning of "mt" in this file name? My guess is that it is related to "release". Is there any standard I could follow? Or if there is any introduction to the compiling flags and library debugging?

Thank you.

Comment: My guess is that it means multi-threaded, for visual studio you can compile to run a specific version of the run-time: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's no standard, just a naming convention. If it's the same of boost stand for multi threading. see

[How can I decode the boost library naming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715164/how-can-i-decode-the-boost-library-naming)

Comment: Yes, we chose it to be the same as Boost.