# How to run a Boost Unit Test in QT Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, boost

It is a pretty basic question but I run out of ideas. I have my example test for my class:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_test ){
       Hero TestHero ("Hika",100,100,100,100,100,100,100,0,100);         
       BOOST_CHECK ( TestHero.getHP() == 100 ); }
```

And these are stored in my tests.cpp file. My question is: how do I run only tests instead of whole app?

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests are usually run in a *separate* executable to your application.

To run the `boost` unit test library the test executable must link to `boost_test_exec_monitor`.

Note: the precise name of a `boost` library depends on your operating system, compiler, multi-threading and debug modes. See: [how can I decode boost library naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715164/how-can-i-decode-the-boost-library-naming).
Boost library naming is usually simpler on `linux`. However, if you define the relevant environment variables then the following `qmake` lines will link on Windows with `MinGW` in multithreaded dubug mode:

```
BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX = $${MINGW_VERSION}-mt-gd$${BOOST_VERSION}

INCLUDEPATH += $$BOOST_ROOT
LIBS += -L$${BOOST_ROOT}/stage/lib
LIBS += libboost_test_exec_monitor$${BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX}
```

You could put all of your unit tests in a single file, but it's better to put the following in a file called `test_main.cpp` (for example) and add it to the source files in your `qmake` file.

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Main
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

Separate unit test files can then be written and added to the unit test `qmake` file, e.g.:

```
#include "Hero.hpp"
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(MyTests)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_test ){
       Hero TestHero ("Hika",100,100,100,100,100,100,100,0,100);         
       BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL (100, TestHero.getHP()); }

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Your unit test `qmake` file should then include the test files together with the relevant source files from your application, e.g.:

```
SOURCES += tests/test_main.cpp \
   tests/my_test.cpp \
   src/Hero.cpp
```

Look in the `tests` directory at: [via-httplib](https://github.com/kenba/via-httplib) for a complete example.