# error when trying to use boost with mingw

Tags: c++, boost, mingw

when I'm trying to use boost with minGW i get this error:

```
C:/Users/matan_000/Documents/Programming/c++-libraries/MinGW/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:676: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
```

and more like this...

I have included:

C:\Users\matan_000\Documents\Programming\c++-libraries\MinGW\include

for the compiler include path in codelite idle 
and included

C:\Users\matan_000\Documents\Programming\c++-libraries\MinGW\lib

for the linker include path in codelite idle.

Im using

http://nuwen.net/mingw.html

because i had the same error with the official boost, so i thought that way it will work.

but it doesnt work...

PLEASE i need help! im going to give up completely :(

UPDATE

I just fixed it with add 
"-lboost_system"
as compile argument.

And i got new weird error.
I fixed it too with add the
"-ws2_32"
as compile argument too.
But i dont what that argument says... And do... If someone can explain me i will thank him :)

Comment: Looks like you forgot to link to the `boost_system` library. Under mingw this is not done for you automatically.

Comment: @drescherjm 
Can you explain me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To link to the 'boost_system' library you need to provide the path to the boost library with `-L` flag and the name of the boost system library, e.g. 'boost_system-mgw53-mt-d-x32-1_67' with the '-l' flag.

If you haven't imported or built the `boost` libraries for `MinGw` yet, there are some instructions here: [boost_1_60_0 .zip installation in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217511/boost-1-60-0-zip-installation-in-windows/35223257#35223257)
. However, please note that you now need to type `bootstrap.bat gcc` instead of `bootstrap.bat mingw`...

Comment: and how I find the name of the boost system library?

Comment: To understand boost library naming see the answer and reference to this question: [How can I decode boost library naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715164/how-can-i-decode-the-boost-library-naming)