# Boost library libboost_date_time not found when compiling project Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

When compiling a project for debugging, an error occurs:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file "libboost_date_time-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib"
```

Despite the fact that the **release version compiles without problems**! **Project settings** for the debug version and for the release version **are exactly the same**!

If look in the folder, then there is such a file:

```
libboost_date_time-vc142-mt-sgd-x64-1_72.lib.
```

That is, when compiling, b2 substitutes the letter "s" before "gd".

Who can tell what parameters to use when assembling the boost. Now I use these:

```
b2.exe -j4 toolset=msvc-14.2 address-model=64 architecture=x86 link=static threading=multi runtime-link=static --build-type=complete --build-dir=build\x64 stage
```

Comment: Here's link to boost library naming conventions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715164/how-can-i-decode-the-boost-library-naming

Comment: Don't forget to add boost lib folder to the list of lib folders in project settings for debug configuration.